# Do I need to change the code if I upgrade my Extent Report from Version 2 to Version 5

Tags: java, pom.xml, extentreports

I have an extent report, which is currently in Version 2. so the details produce by the extent report are not enough. so I want to upgrade the version from 2 to latest version (v5). so do I need to change the Java code for it or only changing the POM.xml is enough?

I want to upgrade it to newer version.

Comment: have you tried with just updating the pom? did it work?

Comment: not yet, is that only enough ?

Comment: try and find out

Comment: I have updated the pom. but It require some code changes as well in Test Listeners and etc.

Comment: so, that answered that question